# Python dash server not updating

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I am learning the basics of dash by plotly. The following code works well.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='input', value='Enter something here!', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='output')
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input', component_property='value')]
)
def update_value(input_data):
    return 'Input: "{}"'.format(input_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

But when I run another example, I get output for the code above.

Please suggest a way forward.
Thanks for your valuable time.

I tried running the code from the command prompt but still didn't work.
I changed debug='False' but still didn't work

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: No error. It just shows output for previous example and not for the current one.

Comment: i m sorry but i don't get the issue: what 'when i run another example' means for you? modify the input? what is you expected output?

Comment: The issue is, as a second example, I am running the following code https://pythonprogramming.net/dynamic-data-visualization-application-dash-python-tutorial/?completed=/interactive-interface-data-visualization-application-dash-python-tutorial/ but still output is for the code I posted above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what i've been understanding of your problem, you are running two apps and you can't visualze the other app.
Well to do so you have to change the port you are looking for:

```
app.run_server(debug=True,port=3004)
```

This should do the trick. You can't run two dash app on the same port.